# I want to update a row based on result I obtained from joining two tables using outer join

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-update, left-join

Now I want to find min value through that cursor c3 and update the Sid = min value we get from that cursor

```
create or replace procedure assign_ticket(cticketid int)
is
varticketid int;
varticketstatus int;
varmincount int;
varsid int;
mcount int;
cursor c1 is select tkid from ticket where tkid = cticketid;
cursor c2 is select status from ticket where tkid=cticketid;
cursor c3 is SELECT support.sid sid, COUNT(ticket.tkid) cnt
FROM support
left join ticket
on support.sid = ticket.sid
GROUP BY support.sid
;
begin
open c1;
open c2;
open c3;
fetch c1 into varticketid;
fetch c2 into varticketstatus;
fetch c3 into varsid,varmincount;

if varticketid is null then
dbms_output.put_line('Invalid ticket Id');
else


    if varticketstatus like 1 then
--        update ticket
--        set status = 2,sid = min(varmincount)
--      
--        


--insert into ticket_detail values (tdid_seq.nextval,varmincount.tkid,varmincount,varmincount.sid,systimestamp,'ticket assigned to support staff');


else 
    dbms_output.put_line('Message ticket already Assigned');
 
    end if;
end if;
close c1;
close c2;
close c3;
commit;
end;
```

**I've obtained Sid from support table and count of tickets that has assigned to each Sid  from ticket table using the following:**

```
SELECT support.sid Sid, COUNT(ticket.tkid) Cnt
FROM support
left join ticket
on support.sid = ticket.sid
GROUP BY support.sid ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes - you can do it using as many cursors as you want, but - why? Use a single `update` instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE assign_ticket (cticketid IN INT)
IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE ticket a
      SET (a.status, a.sid) =
             (SELECT 2, MIN (x.cnt)
                FROM (  SELECT t.tkid,
                               t.status,
                               s.sid,
                               COUNT (*) cnt
                          FROM support s LEFT JOIN ticket t ON t.sid = s.sid
                         WHERE t.tkid = cticketid
                      GROUP BY t.tkid, t.status, s.sid) x
               WHERE x.status = 1)
    WHERE EXISTS
             (SELECT NULL
                FROM support s1 LEFT JOIN ticket t1 ON t1.sid = s1.sid
               WHERE     t1.tkid = cticketid
                     AND t1.status = 1);
END;
```